# LaTeX hangs, Maintenance directory empty, after re-installation of MiKTeX

Tags: pdftex

I had MiKTeX reinstalled by our IT, now the Maintenance directory is empty and any text processing hangs (blue circle circling forever).

The file I try to process is

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

TeXStudio responds with

Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "document".tex

When I terminate it, it says

Could not start Build & View: PDFLaTeX:
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "document".tex

When I try to use the MikTeX Console  and update packages I get

MikTeX Error Report-MikTeX Console

Windows API error 5: Access is denied.

(Actually I do not have admin privileges on my work PC. so I am under "Stay in user mode")

Details:

path="C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\1756f6ade37d5f870f23c05a7f81e257.fndb"

what Permissions am I supposed to have for  1756f6ade37d5f870f23c05a7f81e257.fndb    I have "read" and "read&execute". Apparently SYSTEM and Administrator also have "Write" and "Full Control".

Why is Maintenance directory empty?

Comment: I have no maintenance directory either. This shouldn't be a problem. Close all miktex related applications and then try again the console. If the access is still denied you will have to find out who is blocking it and why (virus protection, other security, wrong rights ...).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what Permissions am I supposed to have for  1756f6ade37d5f870f23c05a7f81e257.fndb    I have "read" and "read&execute"

Comment: Normally if the fndb is blocked this is due to an open miktex console + running pdftex at the same time, or to some overeager security software, wrong rights are possible too but less probable.